# Jumping /scrolling to a specific px from top of page using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I created a button that when the user clicks it should scroll the page and start the top of the page from top:600px.  I have read about scrolltop() but what i understand is i need to create an id and make it an anchor.  Is there a way to do this without creating an anchor but with the height of the actual page in px ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to scroll the page at top:600px when the user click the button#myButton.

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:'600px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WHJzw/) for working demo.